# Linear plot as pgf plot

Tags: pgfplots

Is that possible to draw a linear plot using pgf plot function? I dont want to add numerical data inside the plot. I want to show a linear relation of two different quantities as a plot. Just imagine, from an origin (0,0) one line moving towards north east direction at 45 degree with x axis.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, 12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=\linewidth,
      grid=major, 
      grid style={dashed,gray!30}, 
      xlabel=X Axis $l$, 
      ylabel=Y Axis $R$,
      x unit=\si{\meter}, 
      y unit=\si{\ohm},
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
      x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east} 
    ]
    \addplot 
    % What should I add here for a result as I want?
    \legend{Plot}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My pgf plot.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plot `x`. With `axis equal` or `axis equal image` you make sure that the slope matches.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, 12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis equal image,
      width=\linewidth,
      grid=major, 
      grid style={dashed,gray!30}, 
      xlabel=X Axis $l$, 
      ylabel=Y Axis $R$,
      x unit=\si{\meter}, 
      y unit=\si{\ohm},
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
      x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east} 
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:5,samples=2] {x};
    % What should I add here for a result as I want?
    \legend{Plot}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My pgf plot.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For general slopes multiply `x` by the tangent of the slope angle. In this case this would be

```
 \addplot[domain=0:5,samples=2] {tan(45)*x};
```

but you can adjust `45` to your angle in the general case.

Comment: Ty for your answer. How can erase all the numbers from axis?

Comment: @Mannie Add `enlargelimits=false,` to the options of the `axis`.

Comment: Can I somehow reduce the length of line? I mean plot length...

Comment: @Mannie Just add `width=5cm`, say, to the options of the `axis` to set its width to 5cm.

Comment: In your picture,  maximum point is (5,5), I want that as (4.5,4.5).. Sorry for wrong representation of my query.

Comment: @Mannie This is controlled by the domain. `\addplot[domain=0:4.5,samples=2] {x};` should do.